# import '~.......` in nextJS project

Tags: next.js

I don't understand where ~ is defined in a nextJS import.

it sure does not correspond to the user's home folder, like in linux.

In one project I have it leads to the root folder of the project

in another project I have it leads to a folder under the root folder of the project.

But where is it defined?  - I can't find any reference on the internet to imports using "~"

Comment: If you mean it as a module path alias, that's setup in the project's `tsconfig.json`/`jsconfig.json` file under the `paths` option. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***babel-plugin-module-resolver*** for path aliasing
https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver